# Determine a category from keywords

Tags: nlp

After clustering process I have a bunch of words that have some similarity. I would like to categorize these words.

For example, If I have this words:

- Linked Data
- Domain Ontology Semantic Web
- Use Case
- Semantic Annotation

Maybe the right category is Semantic Web.

I know this kind of problems could be solved wit NLP, but I new in NLP and I don't know where to start. Anyone could say me what the correct way is? or If it's reachable?

Note: I found similar problems They have solved with collocation and POS tagging. Could I apply it for this specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could search for papers on Topic Labelling - It is generally considered a pretty hard problem.  A paper such as the following is probably a good place to start though.  The authors have a few others that are relevant as well.

Lau, J. H., Grieser, K., Newman, D., & Baldwin, T. (2011, June). Automatic labelling of topic models. In Proceedings of the 49th Annual Meeting of the Association for Computational Linguistics: Human Language Technologies-Volume 1 (pp. 1536-1545). Association for Computational Linguistics.

Comment: Hmmm, not exactly the canonical reference for topic models but a very good read on topic models!

Comment: I think the canonical reference for topic model is: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/topicmodeling.html

Comment: @Marc Tomlinson Thanks, definitely worth reading. I enjoy too much reading that paper. I would like to do that experiment and try for myself that results. I will give the link of the paper if anyone wants to read: http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P11-1154

Comment: @alvas This site have many information about topic models. I want to try LDA with my topic terms and see how it behaves, because I don't have documents. I have some keywords and I want to associate a label to that keywords. I found out that Apache Mahout has LDA. So I will start playing with it. Thanks for your suggestions guys I will be so grateful for any other suggestion.

Comment: If you're interested, (Disclaimer: Shameless plugs for ontological entity linking http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2015/cdrom/pdf/SemEval155.pdf and http://goo.gl/PCCrs)

Comment: And if you need documents for LDA, you can try wikipedia dumps.

Comment: @alvas I execute LDA with Collapsed Variational Bayes algorithm. I took a cluster that I get as a result of another process. I took all the keywords and titles from papers as my input data. After that I got as a result some categories labels, but I would like to enrich my results. So could I do that with wikipedia dumps, and how could I do that? Because in the paper of "Automatic labelling of topic models" they tried that and they got incredible results.

Comment: Other publication from Baldwin T. where they get more efficient results. http://aclweb.org/anthology/C16-1091